# Using scanf() to obtain a single integer

Tags: c, integer, scanf

I'm just using this small program to save myself from iterating through all the possible combinations of three dice on paper. It accepts an input using scanf() and then checks every combination to see if the sum of the dice is the provided number.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int a,b,c,s,num=0;
    printf("Enter the desired sum:");
    scanf("%d",&s);
    printf("Seeking for sums of %d",s);
    for(a=1; a++; a<=6) {
        for(b=1; b++; b<=6) {
            for(c=1; c++; c<=6) {
                if(a+b+c==s) {
                    num++;
                    printf("Die 1: %d, Die 2: %d, Die 3: %d",a,b,c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the program doesn't proceed past the scanf statement. I can't find anything in the documentation for scanf that would suggest what I'm doing wrong. I have run into this issue before and was able to get around it, but I would like to know the real reason why this occurs. I am not concerned about checking for valid integer input as I will only use this myself and I know that I will be inputting an integer.

Comment: How do you provide the input? From keyboard?

Comment: Print newline at the end of your output, i.e. `printf("Seeking for sums of %d\n",s);`. Same for another `printf`.

Comment: You've not tested the return value from `scanf()`; you should have `if (scanf("%d", &s) != 1) { ...handle error or EOF... }`.

Comment: These loops are dubious at best (undefined behaviour because of integer overflow): `for(a=1; a++; a<=6) {` should be `for (a = 1; a <= 6; a++) {` -- change thrice.  But Marian's comment is the main reason why you're not seeing any output; `printf()` doesn't write to screen until its buffer fills or you output a newline.

Comment: Oh dear, thank you all very much - I have been away from programming for a while and didn't even notice I messed up the loop structure. The newlines got me past the scanf problem, thanks Marian.

Answer (score -1):

```
the following code fixes each of the problems
and not to insult georgia, but the 'georgian' method of braces is 
IMO: a clutter of the code that makes it difficult to read

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() 
{
    int a,b,c,s,num=0;
    printf("Enter the desired sum:");
    scanf(" %d",&s);    // note leading space in format string
    printf("Seeking for sums of %d",s);
    fflush(stdout);

    for(a=1; a++; a<6)         // note range 0...5 not 0...6
    {
        for(b=1; b++; b<6)     // note range 0...5 not 0...6
        {
            for(c=1; c++; c<6) // note range 0...5 not 0...6 
            {
                if(a+b+c==s) 
                {
                    num++;
                    printf("Die 1: %d, Die 2: %d, Die 3: %d\n",a,b,c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already tried the leading space in scanf before I posted the question and it didn't seem to solve the problem. Marian's comment about the newlines was actually the issue and after fixing that along with the loop structure as per Jonathan's comment, my problem was solved. Thanks for the answer though!